# PHP Printing Conditions Unxepectedly

Tags: php

Hi Guys i am having a very peculiar problem i have written a small code so that it is possible to sign up to the website i am creating with a few restrictions to each field however from what i see the code seems ok but each time i try to use the php code with html code the browser is always printing part of the code like this:

"11){ echo 'Username needs at least 6 and maximum 11 characters'; } else if (strpos($Username, '@') != 0) { echo ' Username cant be your email'; } ?>"

```
    <?php
        $Username = 'aasd';
            if (strlen($Username) < 6 || strlen($Username) > 11){ 
             echo 'Username needs at least 6 and maximum 11 characters';
     }
     else if (strpos($Username, '@') != 0) {      
           echo ' Username cant be your email';
     } 
        ?>
```

From what i can see the code is correct but i can't seem to find the reason as to why this is happening am i missing something in the PHP code? do i have some condition or operator that is not set in the right way?

Thank you first hand to all those who reply

Comment: are you sure file extension is .php ?

Comment: Either you have not install PHP or the file extension is not .php . check both the condition.

Comment: Once check the extension of the file... If its ok.. check whether there are any PHP blocks not opened or not closed inside HTML...

Comment: I run your code .. I am not getting such problem..
Output:'Username needs at least 6 and maximum 11 characters'

Comment: Sorry all the problems already been resolve as simply as i forgot to run it with xampp